# python xml.etree conditional crash (FreeCAD/console)

Tags: python, xml.etree, freecad

I'm trying to figure out what the difference is to two cases of using ElementTree.parse. In one case it crashes, but not in the other.

Case one FreeCAD;
Inside FreeCAD's python console I have the following:

```
Python 3.6.10 (default, Jan 16 2020, 09:12:04) [GCC] on linux
Type 'help', 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Web', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Tux', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Test', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/TechDraw', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Surface', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Start', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Spreadsheet', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Sketcher', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Show', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Ship', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Robot', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/ReverseEngineering', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Raytracing', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Points', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Plot', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Path', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/PartDesign', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Part', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/OpenSCAD', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/MeshPart', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Mesh', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Measure', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Material', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Inspection', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Import', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Image', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Idf', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Fem', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Drawing', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Draft', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Complete', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Arch', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/AddonManager', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/lib64', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/lib', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Ext', '', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/_import_failed', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Macro']
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree
>>> tree=ElementTree.parse("/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Material/MatPropDict.xml")
```

In this case, parsing the file cause FreeCAD to crash.

Case two standalone;
In a standalone python console I have the following:

```
Python 3.6.10 (default, Jan 16 2020, 09:12:04) [GCC] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/lib')
>>> import FreeCAD
FreeCAD 0.18, Libs: 0.18RUnknown
>>> sys.path
['/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Web', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Tux', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Test', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/TechDraw', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Surface', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Start', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Spreadsheet', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Sketcher', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Show', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Ship', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Robot', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/ReverseEngineering', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Raytracing', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Points', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Plot', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Path', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/PartDesign', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Part', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/OpenSCAD', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/MeshPart', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Mesh', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Measure', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Material', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Inspection', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Import', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Image', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Idf', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Fem', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Drawing', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Draft', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Complete', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Arch', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/AddonManager', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/lib64', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/lib', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Ext', '', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/_import_failed', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/lib', '', '/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Macro']
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree
>>> tree=ElementTree.parse("/usr/lib64/FreeCAD/Mod/Material/MatPropDict.xml")
>>>
```

In this case there seems to be no issue.

Is there some setting or initilization that xml.etree depends on that could cause this difference?

The crash also occurs with the following minimalistic XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MatPropDict>
    <Group Name="User defined">
    </Group>
</MatPropDict>
```

Edit:

I found the following difference

```
from xml.parsers import expat
expat.EXPAT_VERSION
```

in FreeCAD gives
'expat_2.0.1',

while in console gives
'expat_2.2.5'

However I can't understand where the difference comes from. In both cases, `ldd` on `/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, (using `subprocess.Popen`) list the same libraries.

Thanks
Torben

Comment: What kind of crash do you get? Do you have a stack trace to confirm that under FreeCAD it also uses the system python xml.etree?

Comment: Two ideas: (1) Add `print(ElementTree.__file__)` before `parse` and check if it is equal for inside and outside of FreeCAD. (2) Try to cut down the XML file and check if parsing crashes for a reduced or minimal file.

Comment: In both cases I have
    /usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py

Comment: I edited the original question to show a minimalistic XML that also causes the issue.

Comment: The crash occurs with just  

    parser=ElementTree.XMLParser()  

backtrace is here
    [1]:https://pastebin.com/74zUwZTT